# Swift - what 'class var' means

Tags: swift

This is one of the solutions to implement singleton in swift.   I am confused why there is a 'class' added in front of 'var'.   As far as i know, the class variable is not supported by swift, why 'class var' work in this case?

```
class Singleton {
    class var sharedInstance : Singleton {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : Singleton = Singleton()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }
}
```

Comment: Class variables are only supported in Swift by way of computed properties. If you were to remove the codeblock defining the "getter" for your property, you would have a compilation error, `"Class variables not yet supported"` https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_374

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's not a class variable, it's a class computed property, which *is* currently supported.

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

class A {
    // Fine:
    class var computed: String {
        return "Woo"
    }
    // Not supported (yet):
    class var realVariable: String = "Woo"
}
```

Comment: +1 for the difference between class variables, and class computed properties.

Comment: It seems like a very odd choice of language phrasing.

Comment: Love to add this from the swift programming language with your answer. "You define type properties with the static keyword. For computed type properties for class types, you can use the class keyword instead to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation."

Answer (score 6):

A class variable is like a static variable in that you access it by calling `MyClass.myVar` however static variables can't be overwritten in subclasses, while class variables can be.